# Trouble understand recursion function python

Tags: python, function, recursion, factorial

I am sure this question have been asked plenty in the past, but I cannot for the life of my understand what is happening in this function:

```
def myfactorial(n):
    if n == 1: 
        return [1]
    else: 
        return myfactorial(n-1) + [n * myfactorial(n-1)[n-2]]
```

I would be so grateful if you could help me understand this; I typically understand other recurssion functions but this one has me stuck. Thank you for any help.

Comment: Please update your question with the exact points where you get stuck. If you understand recursion, this code doesn't look that difficult.

Comment: [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953) Please retake the [tour], read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic), and [ask]. "Tell me how my program works" is off-topic for this site. 
You have to ask a _specific question_ about your code. What do you not understand about it?

Comment: quamrana, this is a really short code; the only thing i am struggling with is understanding how the output is being generated through the recursion.

Comment: What do you mean output? There is no output, only values returned. Just like lots of other recursive functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def myfactorial(n):
    if n == 1: 
        return [1]
    else: 
        return myfactorial(n-1) + [n * myfactorial(n-1)[n-2]]
```

This is probably easiest to visualise with a small n value

When n = 2, we skip the if and go to the else loop

```
return myfactorial(1) + [2 * myfactorial(1)[0]] 
# Then, since if n == 1 we return [1] from myfactorial()
return [1] + [2 * [1][0]]
return [1] + [2]
return [1, 2]
```

Similarly, we can do something similar for n = 3

```
return myfactorial(2) + [3 * myfactorial(2)[1]]
# Since we know from the above that myfactorial(2) = [1, 2]
return [1, 2] + [3 * [1, 2][1]]
return [1, 2] + [3 * 2]
return [1, 2, 6]
```

And, for interests sake, for n = 4

```
return myfactorial(3) + [4 * myfactorial(3)[2]]
return [1, 2, 6] + [4 * [1, 2, 6][2]]
return [1, 2, 6, 24]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This was an excellent explanation. Could you revise the example but with n = 3? Thank you again.